# Windows 7 NTFS Symbolic Link - Network Share Availability/Timeout

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, symbolic-link, mklink, unc

In Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008, is there a way to quickly detect if the target of a symbolic link is available?

For example, a symbolic link is created to a remote share UNC using the following command,

```
mklink /D c:\test \\remote-server\share
```

Now, if the remote share can no longer be reached (for example, the remote server is shutdown), attempting to access `c:\test` can take a number of seconds to timeout and fail.  Eventually, Windows will display an error saying that the target is not available.  Specifically, `dir c:\test` will output "File Not Found", `cd /D c:\test` will output "The network path was not found.", and Windows explorer will show an error stating "The specified network name is no longer available".

Is there a way to check the availability of `c:\test` without incurring that long timeout, or can the timeout value be adjusted?

Comment: The timeout can probably be adjusted, but not removed entirely. I don't know how to adjust it, but I would be careful not to set it too low or it will kill legitimate connections

Comment: Good question +1, did you find out how to adjust it (the timeout)? Exactly the same issue for me.

Comment: @HorstWalter Sorry, I haven't found an answer yet.  I would appreciate it if you post any additional information you find.  Thanks!

Comment: Will do, but this seems obviously a tricky one. Also questions with UNC path / timeout do not have answers: http://serverfault.com/questions/253690/how-can-i-adjust-the-timeout-for-unc-network-shares-under-windows-7

Comment: @HorstWalter good link that sparked a thought.  I've posted an answer there: http://serverfault.com/a/426522/96889.  Give that a try.  If it works, I can post a referral answer here.

Comment: See comment on your serverfault answer